# Конвертация аудиоформатов

Tags: аудио

Мне надо написать программу аудиоконвертер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти исходник такой программы, она должна конвертировать форматы wav, ogg, mp3, FLAC, WMA и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте набор библиотек ffmpeg. Они позволяют конвертировать из одних форматов в другие. Пример конвертации из wav в mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -acodec libmp3lame audio.mp3
```

Comment: А что можно использовать для конвертирования из ogg в MP3 и наоборот из mp3 в ogg и wav???